# Ant: passing compilerarg into javac

Tags: java, memory, ant, heap-memory, javac

I have ant script that compiles:

```
            <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.dist.dir}">
               ...  
               <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
            </javac>
```

I need to increase heap memory of compiler, so I've put the following arguments into `compileargs`:

```
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked -Xms128m -Xmx512m" />
```

But I get an error in console:

```
[javac] javac: invalid flag: -Xms128m
[javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Why does it happen? How do I increase memory used by `javac`?

Comment: is it an copy/paste error that error message say different value than one provided (32m/128m) ?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass each argument in a separate <compilerarg /> element?

Comment: @ZeissS: separate `<compilerarg />` element causes the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 62, accepted):

By default, `<javac>` runs in-process with Ant.  It is a general limitation of Java that you can't adjust a JVM process' `Xms` and `Xmx` once that JVM process has launched.  So, the error message that you are seeing is the software rejecting your attempt to violate this principle (using an unhelpful, unfriendly error message.)

If, however, you specify the attribute `fork="true"` on the `<javac>` tag you *will* be able to specify a new `Xms` and `Xms`. This is because `fork` instructs Ant to launch a new JVM subprocess in which to run `javac`.  Because the JVM process is new, it gives Ant an acceptable opportunity to specify `Xms` and `Xmx` for it.

---

You might try something like this:

```
<project name="project" default="all" basedir="[yourvalue]">
    <target name="all">
        <javac srcdir="[yourvalue]" destdir="[yourvalue]" fork="true">
            <!-- javac requires that -Xmx and -Xms be prefixed with -J -->
            <compilerarg line="-J-Xms128m -J-Xmx512m" />
        </javac>
    </target>
</project>
```

(Notice I am using `compilerarg line=""` rather than `compilerarg value=""`.  The `line` attribute lets you specify multiple space-separated arguments.  The `value` attribute is for passing a single argument.)

---

Ant will wait for the forked `<javac>` to exit, which happens after the `javac` process finishes its work (i.e. compiling).  Ant then continues running the build script inside its own original JVM process.  Ant will check if the forked `javac` failed or succeeded, and take the usual actions based on this information.

---

**Performance**

It's usually more performant to *not* fork `javac`, and instead simply tune the relevant memory settings for the initial Ant JVM overall.  This is often (but not always) the best choice because launching a separate JVM is usually slower and takes more memory than simply allowing `javac` to run in-process.

If you are using the Ant-provided `ant.bat` or `ant.sh` to launch Ant, an easy way to tune Ant's `Xms` and `Xmx` is to define the environment variable ANT_OPTS to contain the arguments you want.  There many ways to set environment variables, but you could just edit `ant.bat`:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `<jvmarg value="-Xmx512m" />` under Java task? For default ones you can use ANT_OPTS environment variable. I found this [example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/perftests/build.xml), not very useful but has a build.xml.

To increase Javac heap space I found this while googling.

```
<javac fork="true"
       srcdir="${basedir}/src"
       destdir="${basedir}/build/classes"
       classpath="${project.classpath}"
       memoryinitialsize="256m"
       memorymaximumsize="256m">
</javac>
```

It's copied from this [link](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/fix-javac-java-lang-outofmemoryerror.html). Setting fork to true is important.

Comment: sorry but `jvmarg` is not valid within `javac` task: `javac doesn't support the nested "jvmarg" element.
`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this problem is really related to ant. You would see the same message if you tried `javac -Xms128m -Xmx512m` directly.

You need to use the `-J` option for passing flags directly to the runtime system. e.g.

`-J-Xms128m -J-Xmx512m` instead of just `-Xms128m -Xmx512m` in your `compilerarg`.

`javac -X` is for passing nonstandard options to the compiler. If you run the command `javac -X` it will display a list of legal options which include the `-Xlint` that you've used. The memory options are settings for the underlying JVM, hence the need to use `-J`.

**Alternative**

There are `memoryInitialSize` (equivalent to `-Xms`) and `memoryMaximumSiz`e (equivalent to `-Xmx`) options for the `javac` task so try those instead of using `compilerargs` e.g.

```
<javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.dist.dir}"
  memoryInitialSize="128m"
  memoryMaximumSize="512m">
```

Comment: The `-J-` prefix yields to the same results: `[javac] javac: invalid flag: -J-Xms32m`

Comment: Please try the alternative solution that I've added to the answer above.

Comment: +1 - Alternative way worked, but still I would like to figure out why not `-Xms32m` neither `-J-Xms32m` didn't work

Comment: I am interested in this myself. `-J-Xms32m` works for me when running `javac` from the command line but not from the Ant task. I've tried using `-verbose` with Ant to see if I can spot the difference in the commands being executed but couldn't see anything.

Comment: @mikej as mentioned in the chosen answer, I believe fork="true" needs to be set for it to pass the -J parameters to a new process.