# How to build using ANT preview features of Java 17 in Eclipse

Tags: java, ant

```xml
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the source.">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" destdir="${build.bin}" compiler="modern" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false" source="17" target="17" />
</target>
```

Eclipse won't build cause my switch contains preview code. How can I enable preview and allow compilation using ANT (build.xml)?

> error: patterns in switch statements are a preview feature and are
> disabled by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Ant [`<compilerarg>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) element, which can be nested inside the `<javac>` element.

Specifically, you need the `javac` [`--enable-preview`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html) argument.

Example:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the source.">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" destdir="${build.bin}" compiler="modern" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false" source="17" target="17">
        <compilerarg value="--enable-preview" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

---

More information and examples for `compilerarg` can be found here: [Ant: passing compilerarg into javac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4134803/12567365)

Comment: Thank you very much, ill check it out.